# is there a java api that supports esmtp pipelining?

Tags: java, smtp

I've been looking around, with no luck, for a java mail api that supports [ESMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP) [pipelining](http://www.spamstopshere.com/blog/2008/05/05/smtp-pipelining/). javamail does not, nor does ha-javamail.

does anyone know of an api that supports pipelining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[netscape.messaging.smtp.SMTPClient](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6028-10/JavaRef/SMTP/netscape.messaging.smtp.SMTPClient.html) provide pipelining (download sources [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/msgsdk/)).

Comment: thanks, I will accept this, but want to leave it open for a while to see if there is a more recent alternative.

Comment: @Paul Sanwald, this is pretty old, yes.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP) : [Apache James](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_James) (since 2.3.0a1)

Although James is a server-side implementation, you may find client-side implementations in the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Niosmtp](https://github.com/normanmaurer/niosmtp) supports both NIO and pipelining. It includes a [Netty](http://netty.io/) transport layer implementation and uses [Apache James Protocols](http://james.apache.org/protocols/) for the protocol layer.